# NIC can not detect CentOS VMware

Tags: centos, configuration, network-interface

I have secondary network adapter on my VM (VMnet 10). I am running Centos 7. Now, I can't detect my second NIC. Here are my configurations:

[image: my configs]

I know that my secondary adapter is ens37 depending on my MAC address of my network adapter 2. I would like to configure it via terminal and via GUI.

[image: ifconfig -a]

When I run the command:

```
 ls -la /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
```

I see the first NIC ens33 and I can't see ens37.

[image: network-scripts]

I can't understand why it was not detected! Is there anything that I can do to fix this problem? Important to note that I added this NIC after the initial OS setup/install, and, I can't assign static IP via GUI.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create the ifcfg file by hand.

I think this may be similar to the problem described here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/715369/centos-virtualbox-no-icfg-eth1-when-adding-secondary-network-interface